# SQL ERROR on stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures and I have created this cursor that will run at midnight every night and rollover the last days record if its not discontinued.  When executed I get an error every time. I'm not sure whats causing it. Any help would be much appreciated.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure nt_rollover_charge, Line 38
>       Incorrect syntax near 'nt_cursor'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nt_rollover_charge
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @id VARCHAR(20);
      DECLARE nt_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT log_id
        FROM   log_book
        WHERE  test_id = '3'
               AND nt_dc_status = 'FALSE'
               AND nt_current_date = 'TRUE';

      OPEN nt_cursor

      FETCH NEXT FROM nt_cursor INTO @id

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE log_book
            SET    nt_current_date = 'False'
            WHERE  log_id = @id

            INSERT INTO log_book
                        (mrn,
                         fin,
                         ref_dr,
                         tech,
                         equip_id,
                         hookup_id,
                         indication,
                         abnormality,
                         location_id,
                         test_id,
                         charged,
                         start_date,
                         nt_rollover_date,
                         nt_dc_status,
                         nt_current_date)
            (SELECT mrn,
                    fin,
                    ref_dr,
                    tech,
                    equip_id,
                    hookup_id,
                    indication,
                    abnormality,
                    location_id,
                    test_id,
                    NULL,
                    start_date,
                    getdate(),
                    'FALSE',
                    'TRUE'
             FROM   log_book
             WHERE  @id = log_id)

            -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
            FETCH NEXT FROM nt_cursor INTO @id
        END

      CLOSE nt_cursor

      DEALLOCATE nt_cursor
  END
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO log_book .... (SELECT` should be `INSERT INTO log_book .... SELECT` without parentheses. Doesn't look like you should need a cursor here anyway.

Comment: also, I think you could do this without cursors...

Comment: @MartinSmith The original TSQL posted by the OP had no `END` at the end of the procedure and so it didn't parse and gave the error above. After your revision, the `END` is there, and the code parses correctly (executing is something different, of course).

Comment: @Pondlife - Ah thanks. I hadn't realised that edit had inadvertently fixed the original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, you shouldn't use a cursor, as that defeats the purpose of using SQL and databases, which is set-based operations. just write your statements like so:

```
Update Log_book set
nt_current_date = 'False'
from
Log_book inner join
Log_book L2
on L2.log_id = log_book.log_id
where
L2.test_id = '3' and  L2.nt_dc_status = 'FALSE';

INSERT INTO log_book(mrn, fin, ref_dr, tech, equip_id, hookup_id, indication,     abnormality, location_id, test_id, charged, start_date, nt_rollover_date, nt_dc_status,     nt_current_date)
SELECT  log_book.mrn, log_book.fin, log_book.ref_dr, log_book.tech, log_book.equip_id, log_book.hookup_id, log_book.indication,     log_book.abnormality, log_book.location_id, log_book.test_id, null, log_book.start_date, getdate(), 'FALSE', 'TRUE'
            FROM log_book 
inner join
Log_book L2
on L2.log_id = log_book.log_id
where
L2.test_id = '3' and  L2.nt_dc_status = 'FALSE';
```

As for your actual issue, what you posted is only 33 lines, but the error occurred in line 38. Do you have an END statement at the end of your stored procedure?